# Evaluation of FileCopyDetails in Gradle CopySpec.eachFile

Tags: gradle, path, copy, evaluation

I am trying to do what seems to be a rather simple thing: **displaying the destination path of the files that I'm copying** using Gradle `Copy`task or method.
To do so, I am using the `CopySpec.eachFile` method, in which I use the use the `FileCopyDetails` to access the destination path, as I thought was explained in the [Gradle javadoc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCopyDetails.html).

Here is an example using a `Copy` task (same behaviour with `Copy` method):

```
task copyTaskUsingEachFile(type: Copy) {

  from("$projectDir/resources/file-with-tokens.txt") 
  into('generated/subfolder')

  filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [sampleProp: 'Hello sample property!'])
  eachFile {  println """ ---- content of FileCopyDetails object used in eachFile :
    object toString = $it 
    name = $it.name
    path = $it.path
    relativePath = $it.relativePath
    sourceName = $it.sourceName
    sourcePath = $it.sourcePath
    """ 
  }
}
```

**Problem is**: every attribute of the underlying `FileCopyDetails` object used in `eachFile` **evaluates to the same value**:

```
:copyTaskUsingEachFile
 ---- content of FileCopyDetails object used in eachFile :
    object toString = file 'C:\<some path>\resources\file-with-tokens.txt'
    name = file-with-tokens.txt
    path = file-with-tokens.txt
    relativePath = file-with-tokens.txt
    sourceName = file-with-tokens.txt
    sourcePath = file-with-tokens.txt
```

I would have wanted Gradle to display:

> sourceName = **resources**/file-with-tokens.txt
>   path = **generated/subfolder**/file-with-tokens.txt

After reading more carefully the `FileCopyDetails` doc:

> Provides details about a file or directory **about to be copied**, and allows some aspects of the destination file to be modified

I start thinking that, at the time this object is printed in `eachFile`, the "final" destination path is not yet set.

I tried to use a **child CopySpec**, with the `from (...) {...}` syntax, guessing it could impact the evaluation time:

```
task copyTaskUsingEachFileAndChildCopySpec(type: Copy) {

  into 'generated'

  from("$projectDir/resources/file-with-tokens.txt") {
    into('subfolder')
  }

  filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [sampleProp: 'Hello sample property!'])
  eachFile {  println """ ---- content of FileCopyDetails object used in eachFile :
    object toString = $it 
    name = $it.name
    path = $it.path
    relativePath = $it.relativePath
    sourceName = $it.sourceName
    sourcePath = $it.sourcePath
    """ 
  }

}
```

And this time I get the following result:

```
:copyTaskUsingEachFileAndChildCopySpec
 ---- content of FileCopyDetails object used in eachFile :
    object toString = file 'C:\<some path>\resources\file-with-tokens.txt'
    name = file-with-tokens.txt
    path = subfolder/file-with-tokens.txt
    relativePath = subfolder/file-with-tokens.txt
    sourceName = file-with-tokens.txt
    sourcePath = file-with-tokens.txt
```

So all destination paths are displayed with their child CopySpec value, but not the part inherited from the parent CopySpec (`generated` in the current case).

So I have 2 questions:

- Does someone know how / when the `FileCopyDetails` is resolved in a `CopySpec.eachFile`?
- Does someone know how to display the complete destination path of the files copied by a `Copy` task (or method)?

Any help or part of explanation will be greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

Using [Vampire answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42670945/1809195), I know succeed in printing, in `CopySpec.eachFile`, the complete **destination path** of my copied files.
To do, I used [`Copy.destinationDir`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:destinationDir) field.

```
task copyMultipleFilesDisplayTargetFolder(type: Copy) {

  printTask 'copyMultipleFilesDisplayTargetFolder'

  into 'generated'
  filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [sampleProp: 'Hello sample property!'])

  /* Here, we print the complete destination path of the copied files, BUT,
     I don't know how to print their complete SOURCE path.
  */
  eachFile { 
    println "file $it.name copied to $destinationDir/$it.path" 
    println ''
  }

  from("$projectDir/resources/file-with-tokens.txt") {
    into('subfolder')
  }
  from("$projectDir/resources2/file-with-tokens-2.txt") {
    into('subfolder2')
  }
  from("$projectDir/resources3/file-with-tokens-3.txt") {
    into('subfolder3')
  }
}
```

Which gives:

```
 ------------ TASK ------------ copyMultipleFilesDisplayTargetFolder

:copyMultipleFilesDisplayTargetFolder
file file-with-tokens.txt copied to C:\<some path>\generated/subfolder/file-with-tokens.txt

file file-with-tokens-2.txt copied to C:\<some path>\generated/subfolder2/file-with-tokens-2.txt

file file-with-tokens-3.txt copied to C:\<some path>\generated/subfolder3/file-with-tokens-3.txt
```

The only missing thing is now to be able to print the complete **source path** of the copied files, in an **easy way**.
By *"easy way"* I mean, by example, in a single `eachFile` that would be inherited by all the child `CopySpec` (as above).

For now, I can display it using [`Copy.source`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:source) field and `FileCollection.getAsPath` method, but it isn't that easy to integrate in `eachFile`.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Vampire is right again, you can use the `FileCopyDetails.getFile()` to access a `File` object representing the source, which allow you to display the **complete source path**:

```
task copyMultipleFilesDisplayTargetFolder(type: Copy) {

  printTask 'copyMultipleFilesDisplayTargetFolder'

  into 'generated'
  //filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [sampleProp: 'Hello sample property!'])

  eachFile { 
    println "file $it.name copied to $destinationDir/$it.path" 

    /* !!!! BEWARE !!!!
    You can't use the below FileCopyDetails.getFile() when also using a filter operation.
    Check https://discuss.gradle.org/t/combining-eachfile-filter-results-in-failure/14801/2
    */
    println "Initial source path: ${it.getFile().getCanonicalPath()}"

    println ''
  }

  from("$projectDir/resources/file-with-tokens.txt") {
    into('subfolder')
  }
  from("$projectDir/resources2/file-with-tokens-2.txt") {
    into('subfolder2')
  }
  from("$projectDir/resources3/file-with-tokens-3.txt") {
    into('subfolder3')
  }
}
```

**BUT**, **you can't use `FileCopyDetails.getFile()` when also using a `filter` operation!**
This is an arcane Gradle bug explain here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/combining-eachfile-filter-results-in-failure/14801/2

When looking at Gradle source, the `DefaultFileCopyDetails` class contains the following code:

```java
public File getFile() {
    if (filterChain.hasFilters()) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    } else {
        return fileDetails.getFile();
    }
}
```

Which, unfortunately, explains the issue.

Anyway, in any other case, my 2 initial questions have new found an answer, thanks !

---

**UPDATE 3 (final)**

And again thanks for Vampire (who opened a Gradle case especially for this issue), who gave us a solution for the former `filter` / `getFile` bug.

See his https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1588 for the details, but, in a few words, to avoid the problem, in **same CopySpec**, you just have to place the call to `filter` **AFTER** the call to `eachFile`.
I do confirm it's working.

Comment: Regarding the `filter` problem, see my latest answer update. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the JavaDoc even more thoroughly, you will find the explanation in the first sentence of both `getPath()` and `getRelativePath()` which say `Returns the path of this file, relative to the root of the copy destination.`.

In your first example the copy destination of the `CopySpec` where you call the `eachFile` method is `generated/subfolder`, so the relative path of the destination file is `file-with-tokens.txt`.

In your second example the copy destination of the `CopySpec` where you call the `eachFile` method is `generated`, so the relative path of the destination file is `subfolder/file-with-tokens.txt`.

Concatenate the copy destination of the `CopySpec` with the relative path and you will get the full path of the destination file.

If you e. g. before your `eachFile` call add a `rename` call like `rename { 'foo-' + it }`, then you will see that the relative path will become `foo-file-with-tokens.txt` while the source path will still be `file-with-tokens.txt`.

---

If you need the source path of the file, you can simply use the `file` property of `FileCopyDetails`. Each `FileCopyDetails` is also a `FileTreeElement` (its superclass) and thus has a file property (`File` object) that points to the source file.

Be aware that there might be interferences with `filter`s. If you have a `filter` in the same copy spec and before the `eachFile`, or a `filter` in a parent copy spec of the one where you do the `eachFile`, no matter if before or after, then you will get an `UnsupportedOperationException`. If you do the `filter` after the `eachFile` in the same copy spec, it works. See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1588 for futher information.

Comment: And I updated my answer. ;-) Btw. you don't need to do `from("$projectDir/resources2/file-with-tokens-2.txt")`, you can simply do `from('resources2/file-with-tokens-2.txt')`. Relative paths are handled like if given to `Project.files(Object...)` and thus are relative to the project dirctory.